# Problem with search operation

Tags: python

I am have two lists:

```
a= [['A', 'B', 'C', 3], ['P', 'Q', 'R', 4]]

b=[['K',1,1,1,1,1], ['L',1,1,1,1,1], ['M', 1,1,0,1,1], ['J', 0,0,0,0,0], ['A', 0,0,0,1,1], ['P',0,1,0,1,1 ]]
```

I want the output like:

```
Output=[['A', 0,0,0,1,1], ['P',0,1,0,1,1 ]]
```

I am trying to search the a in b using the a[idx][0]. Then I want to collect those items and would like the Output something like above.

My code looks like:

```
Output=[]
for idx in range(len(Test)):
    a_idx = [y[0] for y in b].index(a[idx][0])
    a_in_b = b[a_idx]
    Output.append(a_in_b[:])

print Output
```

This does not give me the desired output. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While eumiro's answer is a better one, you asked for a version which uses index. My version seems to work consistently:

```
a= [['A', 'B', 'C', 3], ['P', 'Q', 'R', 4]]
b=[['K',1,1,1,1,1], ['L',1,1,1,1,1], ['M', 1,1,0,1,1], ['J', 0,0,0,0,0], ['A', 0,0,0,1,1], ['P',0,1,0,1,1 ]]
src = [y[0] for y in b]; # I moved this out here so that it is only calculated once
Output = []
for i in range(len(a)):  # You have Test here instead??? Not sure why
     ai  = src.index( a[ i ][ 0 ] )
     Output.append( b[ ai ][:] )
```

Answer (score 9):

First, convert `b` to a dictionary:

```
b=[['K',1,1,1,1,1], ['L',1,1,1,1,1], ['M', 1,1,0,1,1], ['J', 0,0,0,0,0], ['A', 0,0,0,1,1], ['P',0,1,0,1,1 ]

d = dict((i[0], i[1:]) for i in b)

# d is now:
{'A': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 'J': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'K': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'L': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'M': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 'P': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]}
```

Then map `d` to `a`:

```
Output = [ i[:1] + d[i[0]] for i in a]

# Output is now: [['A', 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], ['P', 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: I would like to use the *index* method. Any other way to use the index for the above code.

Comment: @user: The `index` method is less efficient here. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: The reason is that I already have a code where I have single entry in *a* and the index method works for that.